# When to use properties and allocation initializing

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I was just working on my application where I needed to set an instance variable of NSMutableData a value. Now I also created a property for my instance variable which means that my program automatically allocates it etc, right? But then I assigned it a value but it was not taking it but staying null. I then manually allocated it and then it suddenly accepted the value. So now my question is what is the need for properties and why do I have to manually allocate my instance variable although I have a property set up for it?

Thanks in advance!

edit: my code:

in my .h file I have

```
@interface FirstScreen : UIViewController{
NSMutableData* fetchedData;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableData*fetchedData;
```

in my .m file I have:

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
NSString* fetchedDataString= [[NSString alloc]initWithData:fetchedData      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Now if I do not implement:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
self.fetchedData=[[NSMUtableData alloc]init];
}
```

fetchedDataString does not have any value. However if it is allocated it has a value. I am confuces when to allocate instance variables and when not to.

Comment: Instead of describing your code just insert it. It's easier to point out your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't allocate. All properties do for you is define the instance variable & implement accessor methods.

I'm assuming by "assigning a value" you mean trying to set the contents of the NSMutableData object you thought had been allocated for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I also created a property for my instance variable which means
>   that my program automatically allocates it etc, right?

Wrong. If you synthesize accessors for the property, an ivar will also be created for it if you haven't created one. But your property is just a pointer... it doesn't point to anything until you create an object for it to point to, and set it:

```
self.fetchedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

Comment: So then what is the difference between creating an ivar in my interface without any property and an ivar with property?

Comment: The `@property` directive says that there are accessors (at least a getter, and a setter if the property isn't `readonly`) for the property.

Comment: so then what would be the difference if suppose I set ivar=whatsoever and self.ivar=whatsoever? I suppose it has the same effect doesn't it? Thanks for bearing with me! Still trying to self teach cocoa and this is a big point of confusion for me

Comment: Depends on the semantics you specify for the setter. If you specify the property as `retain`, the setter will retain `whatsoever`. If you specify `copy`, it'll copy it.

Answer (score 0):

That's C. What you're saying is true for *every single variable, whether it's local or an instance variable.* It's one thing to declare storage for a variable (that's all you're doing by declaring a property). It's another to give it a value. This declaration in code:

```
NSMutableArray* arr;
```

...does not cause `arr` to take on any particular value (under ARC it's nil; prior to ARC it could be anything at all). It is certainly not an empty mutable array! But that's exactly analogous to what you're doing when you declare a property.

If this is the first value the variable is to adopt, that's called initializing. You might say in code:

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array];
```

But you can't do that in a property declaration, so you have to initialize at some later time while the code is running. A typical approach is to do this in your designated initializer, so that no matter what happens later there will be an actual array at this address, from very early on.

I've written a book on this topic (iOS programming), and the chapter dealing with the issue you're having is free to read online:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html

Comment: All ivars, including those which are synthesized, are initialized to the appropriate `0` value under both MRR _and_ ARC. Only auto variables will have undefined value in MRR.